# I want to use the function .head() for a groupby object

Tags: python, pandas

```
df_collection = dict(tuple(data.groupby('LOCATION').head(2)))
```

I want to group the df by geographic information and make for each country an own df in a dict so that I can assign different names. Moreover I want that only the first two years of each country are assigned to this new Dataframe therefore I wanted to use head(2) but I receive the error message:

> dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 8; 2 is required

```
df_collection[('AUS')].head(2)
```

this works but what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is using word tuple()

On calling tuple, it takes all column names as separate values while on calling direct head() considers one rows of 8 columns as 1 series value.

Thereby, dictionary expects 2 records via dataframe while, tuple gives 8 (number of columns in dataFrame)

This, should work for you.

```
df_collection = dict(data.groupby('LOCATION').head(2))
```